# Flutter apps always opened when screen locked

Tags: android, flutter, dart

just asking
My app allways opened when screen was locked, and i unlocked, my app still alive, if press back button or close the app, lockscreen is show.

Do i something wrong?

Im not using wakelock or similiar package.

flutter version 2.0.1

here my code for main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(
    GetMaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.interTextTheme(),
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///disable automatic ui adjustment for navBar and notificationBar
    WidgetsBinding.instance.renderView.automaticSystemUiAdjustment = false;

    ///only potrait orientation use
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);

    ///set overlay style of NavBar and StatusBar
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
//        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.interTextTheme(
          Theme.of(context).textTheme,
        ),
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PageSplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

just remove this definition or set the value to `false` in your *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
android:showWhenLocked="false"
```